# WPF CommandBindings, ViewModel and UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, icommand, commandbinding

I'm quite new to WPF so it would be better that I will describe the intent:

I have multiple User Controls inside the main window. Each User Control has its own buttons, that I would like to bind to command using keyboard shortcuts.

The `MainWindow.xaml` is something like this:

```
<Window ...>
   <Window.DataContext>
      <viewModel:MainViewModel/>
   </Window.DataContext>    
   ...
   <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                   Margin="5"
                   Content="{Binding HomeToolbarView}"/>
    ...
</Window>
```

As you can See, I'm using some VM binding inside the Code-Behind. In `app.xaml`:

```
<Application ...>
   <Application.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           ...
           <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:HomeToolbarViewModel}">
               <view:HomeToolbar/>
           </DataTemplate>
           ...
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Where I bind the `HomeToolbar` to its `HomeToolbarViewModel` and in `MainViewModel`:

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject {
    // This is bound to the XAML
    private object homeToolbarView;
    ...
    public HomeToolbarViewModel HomeToolbarVM { get; set; }
    ...
    public object HomeToolbarView
    {
        get { return homeToolbarView; }
        set
        {
            homeToolbarView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    ...

    public MainViewModel() {
        ...
        HomeToolbarVM = new HomeToolbarViewModel();
        homeToolbarView = HomeToolbarVM;
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally the `HomeToolbar.xaml`:

```
<UserControl xmlns:self="clr-namespace:ChordTuner.MVVM.ViewModels"
             ...>
    <UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <!-- Error: Compiler binds this to the DataContext of the view, i.e. HomeToolbar.xaml.cs,  and not to the real DataContext, i.e. the HomeToolbarViewModel!
        <CommandBinding Command="self:HomeToolbarCommands.NewCommand" Executed="{Binding NewCommand_Executed}" .../> />
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <!-- Only to simplify -->
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="self:HomeToolbarCommands.NewCommand" />
        <!-- No error, the command is correctly bound to the DataContext, i.e. the VM! -->
        <Button Command={Binding ARelayCommandProp}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

With `HomeToolbarViewModel.cs`:

```
namespace ChordTuner.MVVM.ViewModels {
    public class HomeToolbarViewModel : ObservableObject {
        ...
        private void NewCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("New from XAML");
        }
        ...
    }

    public static class HomeToolbarCommands
    {
        public static readonly RoutedUICommand NewCommand = new RoutedUICommand
        (
            "New1",
            "New2",
            typeof(HomeToolbarCommands),
            new InputGestureCollection()
            {
                 new KeyGesture(Key.N, ModifierKeys.Control)
            }
        );}
}
```

Visual Studio outputs the following error:

> CS1061 'HomeToolbar' does not contain a definition for 'NewCommand_Executed' and no accessible extension method 'NewCommand_Executed' accepting a first argument of type 'HomeToolbar' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    ChordTuner

It is strange to me that buttons using `RelayCommand` class are correctly bound to the the view model (as instructed in `app.xaml`), but the `CommandBindings` does not.

The goal of all of this is to assign global shortcuts to all User Control buttons. Using `InputBindings` imposes that User Control is focused. But I have multiple User Controls that need to respond to differente commands/shortcuts regardless focus.

**UPDATE**
This is the `HomeToolbarView` constructor

```
public HomeToolbar()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int index = 0; index < MidiIn.NumberOfDevices; index++)
    {
        midiInComboBox.Items.Add(MidiIn.DeviceInfo(index).ProductName);
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < MidiOut.NumberOfDevices; index++)
    {
        midiOutComboBox.Items.Add(MidiOut.DeviceInfo(index).ProductName);
    }

    // This event is called when DataContext is changed. This happens because we binded the HomeToolbarViewModel inside the app.xaml.
    DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(HomeToolbar_DataContextChanged);
}
...

void HomeToolbar_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    viewModel = (HomeToolbarViewModel?)DataContext;

    if (viewModel == null) return; 

    if (MidiOut.NumberOfDevices > 0)
    {
        viewModel.SelectedMidiOutIndex = 0;
    }

    if (MidiIn.NumberOfDevices > 0)
    {
        viewModel.SelectedMidiInIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Do someone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that but everything is wrong here. The view model is not allowed to handle user input events like key gestures. This is the responsibility of the view. Routed commands are only intended to be handled in the view. They are essentially a special form of routed events. `CommnadBinding` is the object that a control uses in order to handle a `RoutedCommand`. `CommandBinding` connects a `RoutedCommand` to an event handler. `CommandBinding.Executed` is actually an event. You can't set a Binding on an event.

Comment: The following article shows how to correctly use `RoutedCommand` and `CommandBinding`: [Microsoft lear: How to: Create a RoutedCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-create-a-routedcommand?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: And why dou you have two view model classes for the HomeToolbar? HomeToolbarViewModel and HomeToolbarVM? The code you have posted will not work. The DataTemplate targets HomeToolbarViewModel. But the ContentControl that actually loads that DataTemplate is binding to a HomeToolbarVM. The types don't match. There shouldn't be two view model classes for the HomeToolbar.

Comment: If you care about performance and fast UI loading times, you should move the for loops to the Loaded event handler. Expensive initializations must generally take place in the Loaded event handler (or anywhere outside the constructor). The code inside the DataContextChanged event callback also looks suspicious. It's because a control should not know the type of the DataContext. Use data binding instead. Depending on what MidiOut and MidiIn is you should probably move the code to the view model.

Comment: @BionicCode never mind in saying what's wrong in my code/technique. It is a pleasure for me learn from best developers writing in this forum. I really appreciate your comments and thanks for putting them in a clean answer. I will study it and I will give a try, adapting to my needs. Your answer seems to be the right one, I will give a feedback as soon as possible!

Comment: @BionicCode I used MVVM in other frameworks, I'm a bit concerned of "chain"-calling, i.e. "Window->SaveCommand->Model->SaveCommand. I will rewrite my UI structure.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that I haven't upset you.  Regarding your concerns with chaining calls (I assume you mean the dependencies) I can assure you that this is absolutely fine and normal. In general, that's how programming works: a caller calls a method, that method itself is the caller of at least another method, which calls methods...

Comment: You have to delegate a UI action to the application (MVVM) model. UI (view) clicks save file button and the button executes e.g., SaveFileCommand of the view model --> view model delegates this operation to the model (which is responsible for data persistence) --> model finally executes the save file operation.

Comment: You should be concerned about the responsibilities and the direction of your dependency graph which must comply with the MVVM dependency graph. In MVVM the model is responsible to read/write data from a data source (e.g., file, database, service). You should ensure that this logic is not implemented in your view model classes. Just let me know if something with my example is not clear. I would like to help and clarify any issues.

Comment: The "problem" here is that you want to implement a global UI command. Unless you want to explicitly bind every Command property to the same view model command you would implement a routed command in the UI. The routed command, once invoked, bubbles up towards the root of the visual tree (e.g., the MainWindow)  like a routed event. The main window "collects" and handles this command invocations and delegates the operation to the view model (which usually calls methods of the model so that the model executes the operation).

Comment: This makes implementing global commanding a lot more comfortable as this eliminates the explicit data binding and data context sharing. Global commanding makes this solution reasonable. Again, the alternative would be to explicitly define data bindings on every button to bind to the same command (defined in a shared data context that is likely different from the current data context). I would consider that not very graceful.

Comment: *"I'm a bit concerned of "chain"-calling, i.e. "Window->SaveCommand->Model->SaveCommand"* - I guess that's the reason why you were trying to directly bind the CommandBinding to the view model. But that's not possible (when registering the event handler in XAML) and in terms of MVVM not desirable or legal. Because routed commands are event based implementations of `ICommand` (`CommandBinding.Executed` is a routed event) this would require the view model to handle view events which clearly violates MVVM.

Comment: @BionicCode, You got it. Because the Save button is in the xToolbar I was trying to bind it directly to the xToolbarVM. It did seem to me redundant that Window handles a SaveClicked that calls SaveCommand in its VM that, again, calls "FinalSaveCommand" in its model. I'm a more than 10-years Apple developer with some apps on the store... And, honestly your suggested pattern is the common and right one, especially in modern SwiftUI framework, where those "chain-calls" are not so bad :-) Don't know why they concerned me in WPF. I left Windows development in 2010 when I used to work with WinForms.

Comment: @BionicCode, one more hint, if I can ask you. The WPF tutorial I followed, that binds views and VMs as I did in app.xaml, shows that the MinViewModel (the MainWindow VM) holds all other view models (as you can see in my snippets, e.g. the HomeToolbarVM). So, Window calls methods in MainViewModel, that calls method in other VMs that call methods in their own models. At this point, maybe it would be better that the Window itself holds all VMs and directly calls methods in specific VM (as needed) rather than delegate its MainViewModel to handles other VMs?

Comment: *"I left Windows development in 2010 when I used to work with WinForms"* - Omg, you are traumatized?! :D  WinForms scared you away from Windows development ;)

Comment: *"It did seem to me redundant that Window handles a SaveClicked that calls SaveCommand in its VM that, again, calls "FinalSaveCommand" in its model."* - This call chain is induced by the MVVM design pattern. The view is not allowed to simply invoke the operation on the model directly (you explicitly want to separate the view from the model i.e. the UI from the business/application logic). And even if you bind the view model command directly to a Button, then the exact same thing is happening (from a call chain perspective):

Comment: 1) The button handles the Click event (= MainWindow handles routed command/CommandBinding.Executed event) 2) In the event handler it references the command, anonymously as the reference is stored in the Command property, and invokes it (= MainWindow references and invokes the command from the routed Executed event handler. This can also happen anonymously if you spend the MainWindow a e.g. SaveFile command property that can bind to the view model ICommand implementation)

Comment: 3) Depending on the operation the command operation is executed in the view model or delegated to the model by calling a method on the model. Whether the view model is allowed to execute the operation is dictated by MVVM. Removing an item from a source collection is fine in the view model. Persisting this source collection must take place in the model.

Comment: Regarding your question: you usually use composition when building the application view model. Of course, you could allow the view to know how the view models are internally related and what their individual responsibilities are. But if you follow good programming principles then you implement data hiding to avoid the strong coupling between types. You don't want to modify the caller when the called method's internals change.

Comment: Same applies to how the view model interacts with the model. For example, the view model does not know how data is saved. It could be a file or a database. The view model simply would call SaveData() on the model without knowing the implementation details. It does not know what types are involved as this would introduce an undesirably strong coupling. The view must usually operate data context based. And preferably this data context must be treated anonymously when possible (this is extremely important when designing controls).

Comment: From a design point of view, allowing any control to know all view model classes i.e. using multiple view models explicitly is not good. The view should only depend on its current data context and call complex operations (that involve other classes) via a single API. The internals then take care and know how the operation is executed and what other classes are involved and how they are involved. Same applies to the boundary between view model and model. Those boundaries are there for a reason (decoupling). Let's not break those boundaries by exposing implementation details.

Comment: However, your concerns are reasonable and good ones. My original intention was to show how to correctly use routed commands and how to implement global commands and gestures. To keep it simple I decided to not care about such important design details. I have updated my example to show how you can avoid the strong coupling between your `MainWindow` and the `MainViewModel` by introducing a dependency property.

Comment: Now the behavior (dependency on the command target) is similar to how a `Button` behaves internally regarding the anonymous `ICommand` execution: the declaring type (`MainViewModel)` and the concrete type of the `ICommand` (`SaveDataCommand`) are unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle global input events, you must use `RoutedCommand` definitions and then handle them at the visual root e.g., the `MainWindow`.
Using routed commands allows you to decouple the different scopes (data contexts) so that each data context don't

- has to define a duplicated `ICommand` property and logic
- has to know a particular scope/data context (that is not their own) only to bind to the `ICommand`.

Using a routed command in this scenario allows to execute the actual view model command from a single place amd within the correct data context.

If commands should have a smaller scope, then define the command bindings on an appropriate common parent of the controls that must share a command action. Every `UIElement` can define `CommandBinding` objects and therefore act as a routed command scope.

**MainWindow.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static RoutedCommand SaveCommand { get; }
  private MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; }

  static MainWindow()
  {
    MainWindow.SaveCommand = new RoutedCommand(nameof(MainWindow.SaveCommand), typeof(MainWindow));
    var saveCommandGesture = new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control);
    _ = MainWindow.SaveCommand.InputGestures.Add(commandGestures);
  }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
    this.DataContext = this.MainViewModel;

    // Handle all executions of the routed SaveCommand, 
    // where the source is a child of MainWindow
    var saveCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(
      MainWindow.SaveCommand,
      ExecutedSaveCommand,
      CanExecuteSaveCommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(saveCommandBinding);
  }

  // Handle the routed command execution and delegate the action 
  // to the MainViewModel (or the DataContext of MainWindow in general)
  private void ExecutedSaveCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    => this.MainViewModel.SaveDataCommand.Execute(e.Parameter);


  // Handle the routed command execution and delegate the action 
  // to the MainViewModel (or the DataContext of MainWindow in general)
  private void CanExecuteSaveCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    => e.CanExecute = this.MainViewModel.SaveDataCommand.CanExecute(e.Parameter);
}
```

**HomeToolbar.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl>
  <Button Content="Save data"
          Command="{x:Static MainWindow.SaveCommand}" />
</UserControl>
```

**HomeToolbarViewModel.cs**

```cs
class HomeToolbarViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ICommand SaveDataCommand { get; }
}
```

---

This is an alternative version where the `MainWindow` is allowed to handle the view model command anonymously, without an explicit reference to the view model i.e. without explicit knowledge of the actual view model type and `ICommand` identity (commands property name or member path).
It's an improved example, but requires to increase the complexity a tiny bit (nothing is for free).

This decoupling is achieved by introducing a dependency property for each routed command. This property can then be bound to the view model's `ICommand` implementation (the same way a `Button.Command` property is bound).
This version successfully eliminates the requirement that the `MainWindow` has to explicitly reference its data context (although this ain't something bad in general, we just strive to decouple as much as possible. Therefore, avoiding this explicit dependency is favorable).

**MainWindow.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ICommand SaveCommand
  {
    get => (ICommand)GetValue(SaveCommandProperty);
    set => SetValue(SaveCommandProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SaveCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SaveCommand", 
    typeof(ICommand), 
    typeof(MainWindow), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public static RoutedCommand SaveCommand { get; }

  static MainWindow()
  {
    MainWindow.SaveCommand = new RoutedCommand(nameof(MainWindow.SaveCommand), typeof(MainWindow));
    var saveCommandGesture = new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control);
    _ = MainWindow.SaveCommand.InputGestures.Add(commandGestures);
  }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();

    // Handle all executions of the routed SaveCommand, 
    // where the source is a child of MainWindow
    var saveCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(
      MainWindow.SaveCommand,
      ExecutedSaveCommand,
      CanExecuteSaveCommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(saveCommandBinding);
  }

  // Handle the routed command execution and delegate the action 
  // to the MainViewModel (or the ICommand bound to 
  // the dedicated command properties in general)
  private void ExecutedSaveCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    => this.SaveDataCommand?.Execute(e.Parameter);


  // Handle the routed command execution and delegate the action 
  // to the MainViewModel (or the ICommand bound to 
  // the dedicated command properties in general)
  private void CanExecuteSaveCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    => e.CanExecute = this.SaveCommand?.CanExecute(e.Parameter) ?? false;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="MainWindow">

      <!-- 
        Bind the command properties to the ICommand implementations 
        of the view model 
      -->
      <Setter Property="SaveCommand"
              Value="{Binding SaveDataCommand}" />
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

The rest, how the routed command is invoked, is exactly the same as in the previous example.

Answer (score 0):

In your View, you have the following:

```
Executed="{Binding NewCommand_Executed}"
```

And in your ViewModel you have the following:

```
private void NewCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
```

This will not work, because a binding requires that the method to bind to must be public.

You should be able to fix this simply by replacing `private` with `public`.

Of course, there may be other problems. For example, I am not sure that you can simply bind to a method; it may be that you are required to bind to an object implementing `ICommand`.  But fix this first, see what you get, and if it is unclear how to proceed, ask another question.